# Is "this way" defined in the rules?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was looking at [Etali, Primal Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtali%2c%20Primal%20Storm%5d), and one of the rulings listed surprised me; the card didn't work the way I thought it would based on the wording.

The ability:

> Whenever Etali, Primal Storm attacks, exile the top card of each player's library, then you may cast any number of nonland cards exiled this way without paying their mana costs.

And the ruling:

> Any cards not cast, including land cards, remain in exile. **They can’t be cast on later turns**, even if Etali attacks again.

I expected "cards exiled this way" to mean "cards exiled by Etali, Primal Storm's ability". Meaning that if I exiled a card by attacking this turn, and exiled a second card by attacking next turn, then both those cards would have been "exiled this way".

However, based on that ruling, it seems that "exiled this way" means "exiled by the resolution of the current instance of this ability".

Either of the two readings seem like they are valid interpretations based on the English meaning of the words. So it there a comprehensive rule that backs up that ruling; where "this way" is defined?

It would be really nice if all Gatherer rulings included a citation for a comprehensive rule that backs up the ruling.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think this would be based on the rules for a "linked ability". This is a single ability, so there's no linked ability which can see the cards set aside by it. It (the ability) can only see the cards it set aside itself).

Comment: @Samthere I thought at first about checking the rules for linked abilities, but then figured that because it was only one ability; it wouldn't apply.

Comment: Yes, the linked ability rules are specifically about multiple abilities printed on a single card. I think it's actually likely that this comes down to a templating convention, not a specific rule.

Comment: I don't think there is a rule saying that a single ability can keep track of its own objects as they move between zones. It's just taken that they can. Otherwise an effect that moves cards between zones with exile as an intermediary just wouldn't work, and that doesn't need special rules to say "yep, it does that." The very first rule of Exile says it's a holding cell to just put things temporarily sometimes.

Comment: @GendoIkari Yes, I agree; I think that the linked ability definition may provide the allowance for an ability to track cards between zones at different times, but because this card doesn't have a linked ability it can't do that. I'm guessing, though! :D

Comment: @doppelgreener, Re "*I don't think there is a rule saying that a single ability can keep track of its own objects as they move between zones. It's just taken that they can*", That was true for the longest time, but we now have 400.7h: "If an effect causes an object to move to a public zone, other parts of that effect can find that object. [...]"

Comment: @GendoIkari, Re "*I expected "cards exiled this way" to mean "cards exiled by Etali, Primal Storm's ability"*", I can understand the confusion. In English, "this way" can mean "in this fashion", and thus not refer to a specific instance (e.g. "People driving this way are a danger.") However, MTG uses the more common use of "this": to single out a specific instance. In MTG, "this way" has the narrowest of focus. It doesn't also include similar instances.

Comment: @GendoIkari, "Cast" is confusing in MTG. Sometimes, it's an instruction to cast immediately (e.g. Etali). Sometimes, it modifies what can be cast when you have priority (e.g. Flashback). And there's no clear way of distinguishing the two. I think this was a factor (perhaps only unconsciously) in creating the confusion over "this way".

Answer (score 6):

No, “this way” is defined nowhere in the comprehensive rules. This specific kind of interaction also doesn't get spelled out explicitly in the rules for [exile](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Exile), [resolving spells & abilities](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Resolving_spells_and_abilities), [effects](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Effects), [zones](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Zone), etc. (Though there are some relevant touchstones.)

However, understanding Etali's behaviour doesn't come down to that definition. Etali works the way it does as a result of being [a one-shot effect](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/One-shot_effects): it exiles some cards, then allows you to cast them, and that offer doesn't apply in future. You may only choose to follow up on this one-shot effect during that ability's resolution.

For you to be able to access cards from prior turns, one of two things would have to happen:

1. The one-shot would have to reference all cards exiled with Etali so far, which would mean the following wording:

   > Whenever Etali, Primal Storm attacks, exile the top card of each player's 
   >   library, then you may cast any number of cards exiled with Etali, Primal Storm without paying their mana costs.
2. Alternately, you'd have to be granted a [continuous effect](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Continuous_effects) to be able to cast those cards later.

In case 2, the effect would have to carry a duration. [Kheru Spellsnatcher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKheru%20Spellsnatcher%5d) and [Hostage Taker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHostage%20Taker%5d) both exile a card as a one-shot effect, then immediately also set up a continuous effect that allows you to cast that card for as long as it remains in exile (that's the duration). Alternately, the continuous effect can be provided by a [static](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Static_ability) [linked](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Linked_abilities) ability, as found on [Nightveil Specter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNightveil%20Specter%5d) or [Hedonist's Trove](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHedonist%27s%5d%2b%5bTrove%5d).

This means Etali could also be written one of two other ways, which would let you cast its spells at any time:

- A one-shot that sets up a continuous effect (like Kheru Spellsnatcher):

  > Whenever Etali, Primal Storm attacks, exile the top card of each player's library. For as long as those cards remain in exile, you may cast them without paying their mana costs.
- A one-shot with a static linked ability providing the continuous effect (like Nightveil Specter):

  > Whenever Etali, Primal Storm attacks, exile the top card of each player's library.
  >
  > You may cast cards exiled with Etali, Primal Storm without paying thier mana costs.

Comment: I'm not sure that the one-shot effect prevents my reading... Karn Liberated has a one-shot effect that exiles a card, and it still has another ability (a linked ability) that refers to those cards.

Comment: Actually, your own example of Hedonist's Trove works also.. its first ability is a one-shot effect isn't it?

Comment: @GendoIkari Karn's effect is different entirely: it tracks cards into exile because it needs to.

Comment: @GendoIkari Yes, and the second and third abilities are linked static abilities that grant continuous effects that let you cast the spells that were tracked into exile.

Comment: Now I see; so you're saying that the ability that lets you cast them needs to be continuous; not the one that lets you exile them.

Comment: @GendoIkari That's right, yeah.

Comment: But I'm still not seeing why that's necessarily correct. What would be wrong with a one-shot effect referring to a group of cards defined by other abilities (or in this case, other instances of the same ability).

Comment: There are also linked one-shot abilities, like on Oblivion Ring, but it still matters there that they are linked abilities.

Comment: For example,  Etali, Primal Storm could have said "cards exiled by Etali, Primal Storm" instead of "cards exiled this way"... at least I can't see any reason why such an ability couldn't be printed. And if it were printed that way, it clearly would have worked the way I originally thought it worked.

Comment: @GendoIkari Yep, if it was printed that way it would 100% work the way you first thought it worked. It would work like Nightveil Specter, which lets you cast those cards in later turns.

Comment: Then that seems to go against your reasoning for your answer. You say that in order to work that way, it would need to be a continuous effect, not a one-shot effect. But we can easily come up with a wording that is a one-shot effect and still works that way.

Comment: @GendoIkari The permission must be a continuous effect if those cards are going to be continuously available later. The permission as a one-shot effect is only available at the same moment of the one-shot effect: during the ability's resolution.

Comment: Is there a reason that this ability could not exist: "Whenever Etali, Primal Storm attacks, exile the top card of each player's library, then you may cast any number of nonland cards exiled by Etali, Primal Storm without paying their mana costs."

Comment: @GendoIkari That would also work, because it's looking at the sum total of all cards that have been exiled by that permanent. No reason it couldn't exist.

Comment: Then that seems to me to completely contradict your answer, which says that it needs to have a continuous effect to work that way.

Comment: @GendoIkari No, I'm not trying to say that at all. *That effect* is two one-shots: one that exiles, one that lets you look at all cards and re-cast them. That would work just fine. That wording didn't occur to me. I am just trying to tell you that this is a one-shot effect, and only applies right then and there.

Comment: Right, but my confusion / misreading was never about the timing of when you could cast them. I understood fine that they could only be cast when the spell was resolving, and not at some other time. The issue was the set of cards that could be cast while the ability was resolving. Your answer seems to be explaining the reasoning why they can only be cast right then; not why the set of cards must only refer to the cards that were exiled right then.

Comment: @GendoIkari I've updated some more to not say this is locked down to continuous effects.

Comment: I think the ability wording at the end of your answer is actually different, because that wording would allow you to cast cards exiled with Etali at any time, whereas Gendolkari's (mis)interpretation of the actual text would only allow you to cast the cards during the resolution of any instance of Etali's ability.

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, that's accurate, it is quite different. I should update. I had misread GendoIkari's post initially when I wrote that.